# Page will reload by using anchor link with absolute URL

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, absolute

The main page is the index.php. I have a header.html, this contain the common navigation menu. The index.php and another page (bajnokaink.php) load from this header.html file the common navigation menu.

**index.php and bajnokaink.php page's content**

In the main menu there is "Üzenj nekünk" menu with anchor link. When I click on it, page scroll down to the correct location. My problem is that, if I click on the "Üzenj nekünk" button on the main menu, first the main page reload and after it scroll down. Probably it happens because of absolute anchor link.

```
                <li class="main-li">
                    <a class="main-li-a" href="index.php#jump-uzenj-nekunk">ÜZENJ NEKÜNK</a>
                </li>
```

If I don't use absolute URL, I have trouble because if I am on the bajnokaink.php page and I click on the "Üzenj nekünk" button, it doesn't jump back to the main page and doesn't scroll down.

How can I solution that, the main page doesn't reload when I click on the anchor link?

I try the relative URL. If I use it, the main page doesn't reload and it scroll down but this relative anchor link doesn't work on another page.

Comment: I just tested with an absolute link and had no problem. The page does not reload, as long as the absolute link is actually the same as the main page you are on. Must be the same exact link. Same protocol (http:// vs https://), same trailing slash, etc. To be certain, you can post the absolute link and a screen shot of the address bar. But I understand if you don't want to post that stuff. Just be sure they're identical.